# passing arguments to foreach loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to pass an argument through an `.each` function, but can't seem to do so. Yet, before the `.each` statement, the argument has a value, but I can't get to it from within said statement.

#### code

```
show: function (new_value) {
    console.log( new_value )        // returns proper information
    $('span[data-xyz]').each(function () {
        console.log( new_value )    // returns `undefinded`

        var attribute = $(this).attr("data-xyz");
        if(typeof new_value === "undefined")
            var new_value = system.defaults.xyz;

        console.log( new_value )    // returns `system.defaults.xyz`

        $(this).text(attribute[new_value]);
    }
}
```

How can I get `new_value` to be received in my `.each` statement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
var new_value = system.defaults.xyz
```

declares a local variable inside the the `each` callback. The variable doesn't have a value until this line is executed, that's why you get `undefined`.

If you don't want to declare a new variable, but rather reference the `new_value` variable from the outer function, drop the `var` keyword.

Learn more about [**hoisting**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting).